# TeamCity cannot run on TFS Project Collections that contain spaces

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, continuous-integration, teamcity

I have TeamCity 7 set up to run CI against multiple .Net/VS2010 projects.  one of these projects is within a project collection that contains spaces, when I try to run a build on this project it adds it to the queue and says that no agents are compatible.  When I click on No Agents it shows all of my agents under the Compatible Agents list.

The other projects I have set up differ only by the project collection they are under.  The projects under other collections (with no spaces), and another set up against Git, all work just fine.  Unfortunately, due to factors outside my control, renaming the project collection may not be possible at this time.

I have already made sure the project collection name is escaped (`My%%20Collection` for `My Collection`, per this JetBrains work item: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-18726) and cannot find any other information on what to do to make it work.

Does anyone have any ideas why TeamCity will not work for TFS projects under project collections that contain spaces?

Comment: Is the double percent sign a typo?  It looks like it should be escaped as My%20Collection.

Comment: No, because % is used to insert parameters you have to double escape URIs with percents in them.  The link to the JetBrains article detailing this requirement is included above.

Comment: Please submit issue in our tracker, as it looks like a bug.

Comment: Looks like the issue is handled by http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-21138 which should be coming out in 7.0.3

Comment: TeamCity 7.1 EAP build 23254 appears to not have the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-21138) in TeamCity that has been fixed. Upgrading to version 7.0.3 or later will resolve this issue.